# How to access localhost on VMware Mac as Guest and Win10 as Host

Tags: server, xampp, virtual-machine, mamp, virtualization

*If you don't understand the question could you please let me know in the comment instead of killing the question?*

Main Host System: **Windows 10 with XAMPP Server Running**

Virtualization App: **VMware® Workstation 16 Player**

Guest OS on VM: **macOS BigSur 11.6.2** (without xampp server, but network is bridged)

localhost address on Win10: *127.0.0.1*

local ip (as in Router) of Win10: *192.168.0. 106*

[image]

I want to open my database in **SequelPro**, but those IPs are not working, Please help me what to fill in here:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.

**NOTE: The following method is NOT Secure in a public web environment. But it's fine for the local development environment.**

First,
Added MySQL Database user with all privileges:

***DO THIS ONLY. DO NOT MESS WITH ANYTHING ELSE to Prevent DB Curruption***

```
 Username (Any): [blank]

 Host Name (Any): %

 Password (No Password): [blank]

 Grant All Privileges with CheckBox. // This is Must.
```

[image]

---

Got my Host Device IP address from the Router Connected Device List. These IPs could be dynamic or static.
in my case, it is `192.168.0.113`
We need this IP Address because "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" won't work in VMWare Guest OS with Bridged Network.
[image]

---

**SequelPro in Guest OS: macOS**

[image]